# Jquery form submit not hitting proper action

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I am using a controller with two actions. One is just a holder to display a view and the other is an action to do en event. So my controller likes like this:

```
public function showAViewAction(){
    //empty
}

public function addUserAction(){
         //Code to create a user
}
```

Here is the form code:

```
<p>
    <?php if(!empty($this->errorMessage)) : ?>
        <img src="/images/view/exclamation.png" alt="error" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>
        <span style="color:#f00;"><?php echo $this->errorMessage; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
<br />
<form id="addUserForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>This section is a disclaimer for requesting obscure data......</p>
    <br />
    <p><strong>username:</strong></p>
    <input type ="text" name ="username" id="username"/>
    <input type ="text" name ="password" id="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="addUserBtn" id="addUserBtn" value="Add User" />
</form>
```

Now in the displayed view i have created a form.  I am using jquery to send the form request to the addUser action in my controller.  It looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    newRequestValidator = $('#addUserForm').validate({
        rules: {
            username: 'required',
            password: 'required'
        },
    submitHandler: 
        function(form) {

            var options = {
                url: 'add-user',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: showUser
            };
            $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
        }
    });
});
function showUser(data) {

    window.location = '/user/';

}
</script>
```

The problem is that when i click the submit button on my form it hits the showView action instead of the addUser action.  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `showUser` is firing on the click?

Comment: AddUser on the Controller side is never being fired on click.  I have a logger and it is never being hit.

Comment: If you put an `alert('Hi there')` inside of the `showUser` JS function, do you get that when you click the button?

Comment: Why are you using JS to post the form?

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to do this? I am fairly new to this, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the "url" option from "add-user" to "/user/add-user".  If you inspect the request in firebug or chrome's built in inspector then you should see the request being malformed.

Answer (score 2):

Your actions are not correctly named?

```
public function showAView(){
    //empty
}

public function addUser(){
         //Code to create a user
}
```

Should be

```
public function showAViewAction(){
    //empty
}

public function addUserAction(){
         //Code to create a user
}
```

**EDIT**

In that case your accessing them incorrectly, you need to use `add-user` not `addUser`

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo on my part

Comment: Made the changes but still no results.  When i click the form button the showAViewAction is called not the addUserAction

Answer (score 0):

Are are you adding the validation plug-in to your source code?

```
 <script src="jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

You can download this from here http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate